# give a Timeout function an Id, but then how do i trigger it?

Tags: javascript, settimeout

If i give an ID to a JavaScript setTimeout function, how do I then execute or trigger it?

```
var timerId = setTimeout(function(){alert('doh')}, 1000);
//timerId; doesn't work, 
//trigger it here
clearTimeout(timerId)
```

Comment: How do you mean, execute it? It should fire automatically after 1000ms

Comment: If you want your setTimeout call to work, remove the clearTimeout line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The action of calling the `setTimeout()` should execute it. I believe what you are trying to do is have this action repeat itself every second. For that you'll need to use `setInterval()` instead:

```
var timerId = setInterval(function(){alert('doh')}, 1000);
// you'll get an alert every second untill clearTimeout(timerId) is called.
```

As [@j08691](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18469102/give-a-timeout-function-an-id-but-then-how-do-i-trigger-it#comment27145063_18469102) says, you probably don't see the alert because you're calling `clearTimeout()` immediatly after you call `setTimeout()`.

---

As a side note, you probably don't want to use the `alert()` function to debug this as alerts are a blocking action - no other JS will be executed while the alert is being displayed. You'll be much better off using `console.log()` to for this type of debugging. It's not blocking and will allow you very easily to inspect your variables.

Answer (score 0):

The only use the return value of `setTimeout` has is to *cancel* the timer, which you are already doing with `clearTimeout`.

If you want to trigger it early, then you should clear it and then call the original function.

For example:

```
function doh(){
    alert('doh')
}

var timerId = setTimeout(doh, 1000);
clearTimeout(timerId)
doh();
```